# MySQL Complex Arithmetic

Tags: mysql, math, logic

I have a MySQL table set up like the following:

```
debts

--------------------------
owed_by | owed_to | amount
--------|---------|-------
Alice   | Bob     | 5
Bob     | Jane    | 10
Alice   | Jane    | 10
Jane    | Bob     | 5
```

Is it possible in MySQL to write a query to return the total of what each person owes? Who they owe it to isn't important, I would just like to return each person and (total person owes - total person is owed)

Getting the total owed is easy enough

```
SELECT `owed_by`, SUM(`amount`) as 'Total Debt'
FROM `debts`
GROUP BY `owed_by`
ORDER BY SUM(`amount`) DESC
```

but I can't figure out how to subtract what they are owed.

Also, as a general rule, is it better to perform action like this in MySQL (if possible) or PHP?

Here is a SQL Fiddle with my sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd7cf/1

Comment: Not very fluent with the language, but can't you just grab two different views of the table? `ViewOwed` and `ViewOwes` each would have one of the name columns and the amount column. Independently aggregate amounts by name in each column, and then just subtract one from the other.

Comment: I'm not the most fluent either, but I'll look into views

Comment: I don't know if it's officially stated as better to do it in MySQL or PHP, but I've always figured it would be better to do it in MySQL, as you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT owed.owed_by, owed.amount - coalesce(owns.amount, 0) as `Total Debt`
FROM (
        select owed_by, sum(amount) as amount
        from debts
        group by owed_by
    ) owed
    left join (
        select owed_to, sum(amount) as amount
        from debts
        group by owed_to
    ) owns on owed.owed_by = owns.owed_to
ORDER BY `Total Debt` DESC
```

Comment: Problem here is that you're only looking at people that exist in the `owed_by` column. Look at this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53a6d/1. The user 'Roger' isn't shown, even though his debt should be -20.

Comment: @Travesty3 I understand that it is indeed what the OP wants.

Comment: Oh, guess that was my misunderstanding then. With all due respect, I'd like to leave the comment there for clarification to anyone else stumbling upon this post.

Comment: This would be a very good solution, if MYSQL had implemented `FULL` joins.

Comment: @Travesty3 Sure. That is just how I understand it. Not quite sure also.

Comment: @Travesty3 Yeah, that is how I intended it to work: I'm only interested in people who have debt to pay off and how much.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine both sides:

```
select Person, sum(debt) as 'Total Debt'
from (
    select owed_by as 'Person', amount as 'debt'
    from debts
    union all
    select owed_to, -1*amount
    from debts
) as q
group by Person;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT od.person, od.amount - COALESCE(ow.amount, 0) AS balance  
FROM (SELECT owed_to AS person, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM debts GROUP BY owed_to) od  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT owed_by AS person, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM debts GROUP BY owed_by) ow  
ON od.person = ow.person
UNION  
SELECT owed_by, SUM(amount) * (-1) FROM debts   
WHERE owed_by NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT owed_to FROM debts)   
GROUP BY owed_by;
```

Comment: sorry, just corrected.  i just don't know how to do an outer join in whatever format of SQL the fiddle supports

Comment: the outer join being "WHERE od.amount *= ow.amount"

Comment: @foampile: This horror of outer join syntax (`*=`) worked only in SQL-Server, not MySQL. It it deprecated anyway and should be avoided.

Comment: i think it actually worked in ORCL as well, i think the syntax was (*)= or something similar.  i prefer it to spelling out "LEFT OUTER JOIN xyz ON..."

Comment: In Oracle it was something like `od.amount = ow.amount (+)`

Comment: The question is tagged as `mysql`. Your answer should work with that. If it doesn't, you should specify in your answer. Something like "This works in MSSQL. Not sure if it works in MySQL."

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `owed_by`, SUM(`amount`) as 'Total Debt'.
(select sum(amount) from debts d2 where d1.owed_by = d2.owed_to) as `Total Plus`
FROM `debts` d1
GROUP BY `owed_by`
ORDER BY SUM(`amount`) DESC
```

Comment: That produces an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. (select sum(amount) from debts d2 where d1.owed_by = d2.owed_to) as `Total Plu' at line 1`

Comment: D'oh, I feel dumb. That should be a comma at the end of the first line, not a period.